# acer laptop, no clue what the module is

Tags: laptop, hardware-detection, components

currently I am wondering, what this slot is.
Seen in an acer Aspire 1080TZ.
(On the top left and top middle there are two RAM Slots.
On the bottom left there is the WIFI module and on the bottom right ... I have no idea.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be just blank space for what would've been either a *second* [Mini PCI Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#MINI-CARD) slot (the same type as your Wi-Fi module, but with enough space for a full-size card, instead of just half-size), or an identically looking [mSATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) slot (for SSDs).

Note how the white "silkscreen" on the motherboard is exactly like the existing Wi-Fi card slot, only pointed in the other direction. It even appears to have some traces going to it, and there's a mounting screw post in the bottom right corner.

I'm not sure if this is a feature that similar models (e.g. more expensive versions) were supposed to have, or if it was an actual slot that someone carefully ripped out.

MiniPCIe and mSATA photos from Wikipedia:

[image: Photo of MiniPCI and MiniPCI Express cards side by side]
[image: Photo of mSATA SSD and 2.5 inch SATA HDD on top of each other]

Comment: christopher2007: Well, you could plug one... if the laptop had an actual port. Your photo doesn't show the port, **just empty space where the port would have been soldered on.** Also, note that mSATA and MiniPCIe only _look_ identical, but are not compatible: the port can only be wired for one _or_ the other.

Comment: I am afraid, but it seems that I can not plug in the wifi module on the right side. there is no female place for the pins to go. Is this maybe missing? Where the silver/white space on the motherboard is? Because if I buy a mSATA SSD (thanks for the hint) I can not plug it in there.

Comment: ok, that is exactly the thing I was wondering. So the female part is missing on the motherboard, damn. So no upgrade posibility for me on this slot I guess?